# Why doesn't Stream.filter run out of memory?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

These two expressions should mean the same thing:

```
Stream.from(1).filter(_ < 0).head
Stream.from(1).find(_ < 0)
```

The should loop around until they return `Int.MinValue`. And that is exactly what the version with `filter` does, but with `find` an `OutOfMemoryError` is produced. Looking at their implementations though, I can't figure out both versions don't produce an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Here is the implementation of `Stream.filter`:

```
override def filter(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = {
  // optimization: drop leading prefix of elems for which f returns false
  // var rest = this dropWhile (!p(_)) - forget DRY principle - GC can't collect otherwise
  var rest = this
  while (!rest.isEmpty && !p(rest.head)) rest = rest.tail
  // private utility func to avoid `this` on stack (would be needed for the lazy arg)
  if (rest.nonEmpty) Stream.filteredTail(rest, p)
  else Stream.Empty
}
```

`find` is inherited from `LinearSeqOptimized`, with this definition:

```
override /*IterableLike*/
def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    if (p(these.head)) return Some(these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  None
}
```

They both have a while loop that discards elements of the `Stream` that don't satisfy the predicate. Because `this` should maintain a reference to the beginning of the `Stream` all of these created elements should accumulate in memory until we run out of space. Unless I am really misunderstanding what is happening here, `Stream.filter` is somehow eliminating `this` from its stack frame before it enters the while loop. The comment in `Stream.filter` on why `dropWhile` isn't used looks like a hint, but I have no idea what it is referring to.

My next step would be learning how to disassemble and read JVM bytecode, but I'm really hoping someone knows what is happening here.

Comment: `rest` and `these` are declared as `var`s; although we *initially* have a reference to the head, it is immediately lost as we iterate over the Stream in the `while` loops. But that doesn't explain why `find` runs out of memory when `filter` doesn't.

Comment: Yes, `rest` and `these` will no longer refer to `this`, but `this` should still be in the original stack frame from the method invocation.

Comment: OK. The key seems to be in the second comment `//private utility func to avoid 'this' on stack (would be needed for the lazy arg)"` ...

Comment: No, that's a red herring. `Stream.filteredTail` is used in place of an expression like `cons(rest.head, rest filter p)`. The second parameter of `cons` is a by-name parameter and would force a closure to be created, which would capture `this` from the original scope. In this case, where we immediately call `head` on the result of `filter`, this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a combination of HotSpot and the way Scala's traits are implemented.

If I turn HotSpot off with `-Xint`, `Stream.filter` will also die with an `OutOfMemoryException`. In the generated bytecode itself, `this` and the variables `rest` and `these` are stored in different memory locations, but because `this` is only used to initialize these variables I believe HotSpot is smart enough to simply reuse the memory location for `this`. This explains why `Stream.filter` does not run out of memory.

HotSpot's optimization to `Stream.filter` should also apply to `LinearSeqOptimized.find`, however because of the way traits are implemented a reference to `this` is preserved. When a method is implemented inside of a trait, Scala compiles that method into a static method. When a class inherits from that trait, Scala creates a small stub method that invokes the static method. So even though HotSpot optimizes the static method for `LinearSeqOptimized.find` the stub method's stack frame still has a reference to `this`.

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely going to file a bug report for this. I just wish I had found a better solution.